# how to get this type of date in php like this Date {Fri Jun 24 2016 10:30:06 GMT+0530 (IST)} jquery standerd format

Tags: php

How to get this type of date in PHP like this

```
Date {Fri Jun 24 2016 10:30:06 GMT+0530 (IST)}
```

jQuery standerd format.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post  your attempts

Comment: can you help me, like this 2016-05-19-T16:18:51.018Z  format of date from this date.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

Also refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for different date formats

```
echo date("D M d Y h:i:s eO T");
```

Output:

```
Fri Jun 24 2016 10:52:42 Asia/Calcutta+0530 IST
```

Answer (score 2):

As you were looking for [`» RFC 2822`](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) formatted date you can simply use

```
echo date("r"); // Fri, 24 Jun 2016 10:59:36 +0530
```

Or if you want to be somewhat like as question you can use

```
echo date("D M d Y H:i:s eO T"); // Fri Jun 24 2016 10:59:37 Asia/Kolkata+0530 IST
```

[**Docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

> In PHP you can get this format as

```
<?php
$tzone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta');
$dtime = new DateTime("now", $tzone);
echo $dtime->format("D M d Y H:i:s \G\M\TO (T)");
?>
```

> In that case you will get the output:
>
> Fri Jun 24 2016 11:25:40 GMT+0530 (IST)
>   **That is your output as you wanted.**

Answer (score 0):

finally got it .... thanks for help..

```
$tzone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta');
$dtime = new DateTime("now", $tzone);
$daet = $dtime->format("D M d Y H:i:s \G\M\TO (T)");
$timestart    = explode (' ', microtime());
$timeInSecond = substr($timestart[0],1,4)."Z";
echo preg_replace('/\+.*/',$timeInSecond,date('c',"1466774626"));
```

//2016-06-24T15:23:46.541Z